# Finding $a_{n}$ of a sum

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

I have the function
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{2n}}{2n}$$
and I have to find its domain and also $f'$ domain. Well, to find the convergence radius of $f(x)$ but when I derivate
$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{2n-1}$$
My point is: how do I find $a_{n}$ of this series above?

Comment: Hint: $\;x f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\big(-x^2\big)^n\,$, which is a geometric alternating series.

Comment: $a_n$ of the series is the coefficient of the $x^n$ term. I would try to write out a few terms of the series to get the idea of what is going on. If there is no, say, $x^7$ term then what should $a_7$ be?

Comment: By $a_n$, do you mean the partial sums of the series? All you need to do to find domains is find where the series converge. The ratio test should suffice for both.

Comment: @Kajelad I mean to find the radius convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n x^{2 n}}{2 n}$$
Derivative is
$$f'(x)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^n x^{2 n-1}=\frac{1}{x}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^n x^{2 n}=\frac{1}{x}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-x^2)^n $$
Is a geometric series which converges when $x^2<1$ that is $|x|<1$

The sum of a geometric series is $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } a^n=\dfrac{1}{1-a}$, so we have to subtract the first term because the given series starts from $n=1$
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}\, \left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}-1\right)=-\frac{x}{x^2+1}$$
so the function $f$ is the integral
$$f(x)=-\int \frac{x}{x^2+1} \, dx=-\dfrac{1}{2}\int \frac{2x}{x^2+1} \, dx=-\frac12 \log (1+x^2)$$
for any $x\in(-1,1)$

The radius of convergence is $r=1$

$$r=\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \left|\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}\right|=\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \left| \frac{\frac{(-1)^n}{2 n}}{\frac{ (-1)^{n+1}}{2 (n+1)}}\right|=\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \frac{n+1}{n}=1$$

Hope this is useful